# Delete row based on one letter

Tags: excel, vba

Need help with my code.
In (Column C) I have values MG01, MG02a, MG02b, MG02c. And in (Column A) different values. Code needs to delete row if value in column A is "1" and
in Column C if it finds letters at the end of text such as b, c, d, e, ....

And with "*c*" code do not recognized MG02c help please.

```
Sub xDeleteRowz()

Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 1 Step -1
    If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "1" And (Cells(i, "C").Value) = "*c*" Then
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `(Cells(i, "C").Value) Like "*c*"`

Comment: Can i put something so it check b, c, d, e, f, g ?

Comment: @dzunaa - Is the letter always lower case and at the end of the value?

Comment: `If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "1" And not isnumeric(Right(Cells(i, "C").Value,1)) Then`

Comment: yes always lower case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like something more suited for a regular expression:

```
Sub xDeleteRowz()
    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "MG\d{2}[a-z]"
        .IgnoreCase = False
        For i = Last To 1 Step -1
            If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "1" And .Test(Cells(i, "C").Value) Then
                Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that the expression requires the value to begin with MG##.  If the start of the value can be different, replace this line...

```
.Pattern = "MG\d{2}[a-z]"
```

...with...

```
.Pattern = ".+[a-z]"
```

... and it will match anything with a lowercase letter at the end. You can also limit to specific letters by changing the range inside the brackets.  I.e., if it's only 'a' through 'g', it would be:

```
.Pattern = ".+[a-g]"
```

Comment: This is what I need Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "1" And (Cells(i, "C").Value) = "*c*" Then
```

to

```
If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "1" And (Cells(i, "C").Value) like "*c*" Then
```

or

```
If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "1" And InStr(1, Cells(i, "C").Value, "c", vbTextCompare) Then
```

May I also suggest that you make some more changes to your code and start coding explicitly like so:

```
Option Explicit

Sub xDeleteRowz()

Dim i As Long, Last As Long

Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(i, "A").Value = "1" And InStr(1, .Cells(i, "C").Value, "c", vbTextCompare) Then
            .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

### Update:

Based on the latest comment a more suitable approach might be the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub xDeleteRowz()

Dim i As Long, Last As Long

Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(i, "A").Value = "1" Then
            Select Case LCase(Right(.Cells(i, "C").Value, 1))
                Case "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"
                    .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End Select
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Can i put something so it check b, c, d, e, f, g ?

Comment: Just updated the code to reflect your latest request. Hope that helps / solves it.

Comment: If you `LCase` before the select, you aren't testing for case.